# Расширение String.prototype показывает производительно ниже вызова функции в 10 раз

Tags: javascript, производительность

Я хотел расширить prototype объекта `String` некоторыми полезными методами. Это работало, но производительность была удивительно низкой. Передача строки в функции почему то быстрее в x10 раз, чем переопределение метода `String.prototype`, который делает то же самое. Чтобы проверить что это действительно происходит я создал очень простой пример, функцию `count()` и соответствующий метод.

(Я поэкспериментировал, и создали три различные версии метода.)

```js
 

function count(str, char) {
    var n = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) if (str[i] == char) n++;
    return n;
}

String.prototype.count = function (char) {
    var n = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) if (this[i] == char) n++;
    return n;
}

String.prototype.count_reuse = function (char) {
    return count(this, char)
}

String.prototype.count_var = function (char) {
    var str = this;
    var n = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) if (str[i] == char) n++;
    return n;
}

// Here is how I measued speed, using Node.js 6.1.0

var STR ='0110101110010110100111010011101010101111110001010110010101011101101010101010111111000';
var REP = 1e3//6;

console.time('func')
for (var i = 0; i < REP; i++) count(STR,'1')
console.timeEnd('func')

console.time('proto')
for (var i = 0; i < REP; i++) STR.count('1')
console.timeEnd('proto')

console.time('proto-reuse')
for (var i = 0; i < REP; i++) STR.count_reuse('1')
console.timeEnd('proto-reuse')

console.time('proto-var')
for (var i = 0; i < REP; i++) STR.count_var('1')
console.timeEnd('proto-var')
```

Результаты:

```
func: 705 мс  
proto: 10011 мс  
proto-reuse: 10366 мс  
proto-var: 9703 мс
```

Как вы видите, различие существенное.

Пример ниже показывает, что производительность вызовов методов пренебрежимо медленнее, и что функции сами медее методов.

```js
  

var STR ='0110101110010110100111010011101010101111110001010110010101011101101010101010111111000';
var REP = 1e3//6;

function count_dummy(str, char) {
    return 1234;
}

String.prototype.count_dummy = function (char) {
    return 1234; // Just to prove that accessing the method is not the bottle-neck.
}

console.time('func-dummy')
for (var i = 0; i < REP; i++) count_dummy(STR,'1')
console.timeEnd('func-dummy')

console.time('proto-dummy')
for (var i = 0; i < REP; i++) STR.count_dummy('1')
console.timeEnd('proto-dummy')

console.time('func-dummy')
for (var i = 0; i < REP; i++) count_dummy(STR,'1')
console.timeEnd('func-dummy')
```

Результаты:

```
func-dummy: 0.165 мс  
proto-dummy: 0.247 мс  
func-dummy: 0.045 мс
```

Несмотря на огромное число повторений (порядка 1e8) прототипированные методы оказались в x10 раз медленнее функций, но это может быть проигнорировано для этого случая.

Это может быть связано только с объектом String, потому что выполняется то одно и тоже, вне зависимости от способа вызова методов:

```js
var A = { count: 1234 };

function getCount(obj) { return obj.count }

A.getCount = function() { return this.count }

console.time('func')
for (var i = 0; i < 1e9; i++) getCount(A)
console.timeEnd('func')

console.time('method')
for (var i = 0; i < 1e9; i++) A.getCount()
console.timeEnd('method')
```

Результаты:

```
func: 1689.942 мс  
method: 1674.639 мс
```

Поиск на Stackoverflow был безрезультатным - кроме общей рекомендации "*не расширяйте String и Array - это засоряет пространство имен*" (что не является проблемой конкретно для моего проекта), я не смог найти связанное с производительностью методов по сравнению с функциями. Получается, что я должен просто забыть о расширении класса String из-за падения производительности добавляемых методов? Кто-нибудь знает больше об этом?

<sub>Перевод вопроса «[Extending String.prototype performance shows that function calls are 10x faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38407760/)» [@exebook](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1968972/exebook).</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего, потому что вы используете `"use strict"`, и `this` должно приводиться к экземпляру `String` внутри вашего метода, вместо того что бы быть примитивом строки.

Вы можете проверить это повторив свои измерения на `var STR = new String('01101011…')`.

Для этого исправьте свою реализацию:

```
String.prototype.count = function (char) {
    "use strict";
    var n = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
        if (this[i] == char)
            n++;
    return n;
};
```

<sub>Перевод ответа «[Extending String.prototype performance shows that function calls are 10x faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38407760/)» [@Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi).</sub>

Comment: Это работает, но бессмысленно  для меня! Я добавил новый вопрос: «[Почему “use strict” повышает производительность в 10 раз в этом примере?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/547484/7575)» [@exebook](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1968972/exebook)