# Почему "use strict" повышает производительность в 10 раз в этом примере?

Tags: javascript, производительность

После вопроса [Расширение String.prototype показывает производительно ниже вызова функции в 10 раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/547482/) мне стало интересно, почему простое добавление `"use strict"` в метод `String.prototype` повышает производительность в 10 раз. [Объяснение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/547483/7575), данное [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi), слишком короткое и непонятное.

Почему такое резкое различие в производительности между двумя почти идентичными методами, единственное отличие между которыми — только `"use strict"` в начале? Вы можете объяснить подробнее и с обоснованием?

```js
  

String.prototype.count = function(char) {
  var n = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
    if (this[i] == char) n++;
  return n;
};

String.prototype.count_strict = function(char) {
  "use strict";
  var n = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
    if (this[i] == char) n++;
  return n;
};
// Here is how I measued speed, using Node.js 6.1.0

var STR = '0110101110010110100111010011101010101111110001010110010101011101101010101010111111000';
var REP = 1e4;

console.time('proto');
for (var i = 0; i < REP; i++) STR.count('1');
console.timeEnd('proto');

console.time('proto-strict');
for (var i = 0; i < REP; i++) STR.count_strict('1');
console.timeEnd('proto-strict');
```

Результат:

```
proto: 101 ms  
proto-strict: 7.5 ms
```

<sub>Перевод вопроса «[Why “use strict” improves performance 10x in this example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38411552/)» [@exebook](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1968972/exebook).</sub>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Режим `"use strict"` не обязывает `this` контекст быть объектом](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#Securing_JavaScript). Если Вы вызовете функцию для не объекте, то `this` останется тем не объектом.

И напротив, в не строгом режим `this` контекст всегда вначале оборачивается в объект, если он ещё не объект. Например, `(42).toString()` сначала обертывает `42` в объект `Number`, а уже затем вызывает `Number.prototype.toString`с объектом `Number` в контексте `this`. В строгом режиме контекст `this` остается нетронутым и просто вызывается `Number.prototype.toString` с `42` в контексте `this`.

```js
(function() {
  console.log(typeof this);
}).call(42); // 'object'

(function() {
  'use strict';
  console.log(typeof this);
}).call(42); // 'number'
```

В Вашем случае нестрогая версия режима тратит много времени на перенос и разворачивание примитива `string` в `String` и обратно. С другой стороны, строгий режим непосредственно непосредственно работает с примитивом `string`, что и повышает производительность.

<sub>Перевод ответа «[Why “use strict” improves performance 10x in this example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38411552/)» [@Mattias Buelens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1321716/mattias-buelens).</sub>